# HOW CAn I Differciate the button click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, button

i have a problem. i m making Some wpf button Dynamic through C#.i m using it A loop for this now i m trying to find all button Click Event.
i find it But It Work Same on All The button Click
how Can i Differciate all the button .

thanks in Advance
shashank

```
`for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Button b1 = new Button();
            //this.RegisterName("myAnimatedBrush", b1);
            b1.Name = "button" + i;     
            b1.Height = 200;
            b1.Width = 200;
            b1.Margin = new Thickness(0, -100, 0, 0);
            b1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            b1.Content = "English";
            b1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Pink;
            b1.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(b1_Click);
            canvasbtn.Children.Add(b1);
            Canvas.SetLeft(b1,b1.Width * i);

        }`
```

Comment: I think you spilt coffee on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be somthing like this would work.

```
 protected void HandleBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            if(btn==null){ 
               return; //This is not expected.
            }
            if(btn.Name=="button1")
            {
                DoFirstTask();
            }
            else if (btn.Name == "button2")
            {
                DoSecondTask();
            }
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Ouch! What a nightmare. SHASHANK's naming of the buttons as "button1", etc, was a poor idea (they do not need names). Nested "if()" on such a name is even worse. At least make it a switch(). And if you handle btn==null at all it should throw an exception not just return!  I would take a totally different tack and encourage SHASHANK to a better design in which he differentiates on something the user will see (color, content, etc).

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

If you want the buttons you create in a loop to all behave differently, think about what is different about the buttons themselves and check for that.  For example:

- If each button is generated from a different data item, set its DataContext and use that to find the original data item.
- If each buttons is numbered, set the DataContext to the button number.
- If each button has a different meaning, set the Click to different event handlers.  You can create an array of these.  Or have a different object attached to each button as a CommandParameter.

Your code will be most meaningful if you distinguish your behavior based on something that is salient to the end-user.

Example:

```
 for(int i=0; 0<10; i++)
 {
   var btn = new Button
   {
     DataContext = i,
     Height = 200, Width = 200,
     Margin=new Thickness(0, 100, 0 0),
   });
   btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
   {
     MessageBox.Show("You clicked button " + ((Button)sender).DataContext);
   };
   dockPanel.Children.Add(btn); // Or you could use Canvas & Canvas.SetLeft
}
```

I would recommend you strongly consider using DockPanel instead of Canvas for this.  Unless you need arbitrary positioning by the end-user (drag and drop), Canvas is almost never the right panel to use.  If you use a DockPanel you won't have to set the left coordinate - it will automatically do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
void b1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button srcButton = e.Source as Button;
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx) & [More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)